# Why does await not wait?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

This is my actual code:

```
    async Task getData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Step 1");

        using (HttpClient api = new HttpClient()) 
            await api.GetAsync("http://google.com/").ContinueWith(
                (getTask) =>
                    Console.WriteLine(getTask.Result.StatusCode);
            );

        Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(getData);
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
Step 1
Step 3
OK
Step 2
```

Why does `Step 3` not come after `Step 2`?

How do I get it to work in sequence, ie to return to the caller of `getData` only until everything in `getData` is done?

Comment: Try `task.Result.Wait()`, but your example seems a little over complicated.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works. Can explain why? How does the control flow managed to bypass the end of the `getData` method to return to the caller?

Comment: It seems like you should really read / work through a proper introduction to async/await (like [this one](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for example). In short: `getData` already returns a task, by wrapping it in another one, you have to wait for inner one. Or just write `await getData(...)` in `button1_Click` instead. But beware, there is a lot more to async/await - really read up more on it.

Comment: Also, you should [never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also mark you event handler as `async`

```
private async Task button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and `await` instead of `Wait`:

```
private async Task button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await getData();

    Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
}
```

When we use the async/await pattern, we should go this way until the first method initiated it. Otherwise, by calling explicitly `Wait` or `Result`, we may run into deadlock issues. Furthermore, calling explicitly those methods you block the executing thread. So you drop the main benefit of using async/await, which is not blocking the executing thread and run on a separate thread some code and once this is done resume the execution of your code from where you stopped.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know that an event handler can be `async`. Does that mean that all code that call event handlers are also `async`?

Comment: @You are welcome. That means that an event can be processed asynchronsly without blocking you application. For instance, if we speak for a WPF application and a button click triggers a netwrok call that it would take some considerable time to be completed then your UI would freeze, if you the corresponding handler is not an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 2):

To try and put things simply and clearly - `async Task` (and `<T>`) methods are, themselves, responsible for allocating a `Task` object which represents their completion.

If you find yourself working with `async` methods *and* allocating `Task` objects yourself (either directly, as here, or using static factory methods such as `Task.Run`), you've got to recognize that more than one `Task` object now exists. You have to be careful and recognize situations where (as here) you create `Task`s that themselves now return `Task`s.

It's far better, if possible, to embrace `async` all the way (as you modify each function to be `async`, you'll then tend to locate each call site and make that location `async` as well) and to stop allocating any `Task`s yourself.